# How to search for objects in a large list in C#?

Tags: c#, database, list

The basic question I have, is: Will the code in the way I write it still efficiently perform when the List "myElements", which I am going to describe in the following, gets larger. In the final program, this List will contain around 2000 or more objects. Here we go:

The task that I have to solve is providing an application that enables the user to search for elements that have certain properties. Up to now, these elements are implemented in the following way:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public string property1; 
    public string property2;
    //+ lots of more properties (ca. 30) that all derived classes contain

    BaseClass()
    {
        property1 = String.Empty;
        property2 = String.Empty;
    }
}

public DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
{
    public string property3;
    //property that only this derived class contatins

    DerivedClass(string prop1, string prop2)
    {
         this.property1 = prop1;
         this.property2 = prop2;
         property3 = "prop3";
    }
}

//+ more derived classes and derivations from them also
```

Later in the code, instances are created as follows:

```
DerivedClass myObj1 = new DerivedClass("text1", "text2");
DerivedClass myObj2 = new DerivedClass("text3", "text4");
```

This is where the list comes in: finally, these objects are added to the list like that:

```
myElements.Add(myObj1);
myElements.Add(myObj2);
//+ List will contain around 2000 objects
```

What I know want to do is creating dropdown menus. These menues will appear on a windows form in different columns. The first column will contain comboBoxes that allows the user to choose properties the BaseClass contains. In the above example the choosable options in one of those boxes (which represents the values of property1) would be "text1" and "text3".

Now, depending on the value of this property from the base class, the user will be shown different results in the second column comboBox. Here, we just have one DerivedClass, so there will only be one option in the dropdown: "prop3". Imagine one more DerivedClass that could contain a constructor with the code

```
DerivedClass(string prop4)
{
    prop4 = "text5";
}
```

I we had an object from this class, the value "text5" should appear in the second column comboBox as well.

Up to know, the population of all comboBoxes is done by foreach loops that goes through all elements of the list "myElements" and adds an item to the comboBox if this item is not already inside the items list of the box. This is done step by step: User clicks a button the first time - first column comboBoxes are populated, user clicks the same button the second time - second column comboBoxes are populated (result depending on values that user has choosen in first column boxes).

My basic question: Every time the user clicks the button, the comboBoxes are filled by using a foreach-loop that goes through ALL elements of the list "myElements". If the list gets bigger, this seems quite a silly solution to me, especially when populating the first column. If there are two classes that derive directly from BaseClass and whose constructors define the value of property1 then the values that the user needs to see in the first column comboBoxes are known at an quite early point of the program.

Can I access these values WITHOUT going through the whole list of elements? Using common sense, I ask myself: if there are TWO derived classes and, therfore, TWO constructors that define property1, there MUST be way of searching that finds these two values not by scrolling through 2000 objects, but by doing somehow only TWO steps.

Does such a way exist? What would be the topics I need to learn to implement it as described?

In addition: Does it make sense to store these 2000 elements in "myElements" in a database rather then in the code itself? Would that still allow the user to "click through" the properties based on the defined class structure? What would be the advantages?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions / literature hints!

Comment: Why are you using a list which take an average of N/2 searches instead of using a Dictionary which has a hash that will reduce searches to Log(N)?  200 items doesn't seem a lot of items to worry about memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you provide an example of how to use a Dictionary?

Comment: Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();

To add :
dict.Add("text1","text2");  To get data :  string value = dict["text1"]; //which will get "text2".